# Remove decimal value from rupees

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN i.[CombinedPhase] = @combinephase
                          THEN i.[ItemQuantity]*CASE WHEN [i].[SourceID] = 10 
                                                          THEN 0
                                                          ELSE i.[ItemPrice]
                                                END
                          ELSE 0
                END)
       AS INT), 0)
```

for above I am getting XML in SP with below output

```
{"Message":"Grand Total:","Amount":"₹898.00"}]}
```

I have tried using cast but not got result

Need to remove .00 from 898

used cast to change data type to int

Actual result should be like

```
{"Message":"Grand Total:","Amount":"₹898"}]}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Since this is SQL Server syntax i have removed plsql & mysql Tag.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle PL/SQL there are two methods.

[TRUNK](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_nbr.php) To remove decimal places.

[ROUND](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/round_nbr.php) To remove decimal places and round the number.

You can use one of these according to your needs.

Edit:

For Sql Server you can use ROUND and CAST to remove decimal places.

```
select cast(round(11.6,0) as int)
```